# Changing asp.net menu orientation based on the device / browser window width with CSS

Tags: html, css, asp.net

What i'm trying to do is some basis responsiveness practices: i'm working on a web application and the client is not happy about how the controls (asp menu/panel ) are mixed and messes when they change browser windows height/width ( minimizing/maximizing ). i have attached here some pictures for the situation i'm dealing with. since i'm not a web designer, i'm posting this entry for some ideas/code samples.

[image: Full size]

and now when resizing, this is when things look weird!

[image: minimizing browser window]

Yes, i know i need to use media queries but the thing is when trying to implement them for changing menu orientation, i can't figure out ( please see picture )

I think i need to post here some essential code for a better approach.

```
div.menu {
    padding: 8px 6px 8px 8px;
    width: 90%;
}

    div.menu ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 5px 3px;
        width: auto;
    }

        div.menu ul li a, div.menu ul li a:visited {
            background-color: #465c71;
            border: 1px #465c71 solid;
            color: #dde4ec;
            display: block;
            line-height: 1.35em;
            padding: 4px 20px;
            text-decoration: none;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }

            div.menu ul li a:hover {
                background-color: #bfcbd6;
                color: #465c71;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            div.menu ul li a:active {
                background-color: #465c71;
                color: #cfdbe6;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
```

Thank you for reading.

EDIT:

```
<div id="content">
                <asp:Menu ID="MenuPortail" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false"
                    IncludeStyleBlock="true" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="SlateGray" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="SlateGray" />
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="1   -  Choisir Langue        > " Value="0" />
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="#" Text="2   -  Authentification        > " Value="1" />
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="#" Text="3   -  Remplir Formulaire        > " Value="2" />
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="#" Text="4   -  Résumé        > " Value="3" />
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="#" Text="5   -  Confirmation       >  " Value="4" />
                    </Items>
                </asp:Menu>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
            </div>
```

Edit2:

Rendered mark-up:

<

```
style type="text/css">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    #MenuPortail img.icon { border-style:none;vertical-align:middle; }
    #MenuPortail img.separator { border-style:none;display:block; }
    #MenuPortail img.horizontal-separator { border-style:none;vertical-align:middle; }
    #MenuPortail ul { list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0;width:auto; }
    #MenuPortail ul.dynamic { z-index:1; }
    #MenuPortail a { text-decoration:none;white-space:nowrap;display:block; }
    #MenuPortail a.static { padding-left:0.15em;padding-right:0.15em; }
    #MenuPortail a.popout { background-image:url("/WebResource.axd?d=u0tdsA78OHekEc59vxJJou2q7ktee2Q9rAKCDlgdCk94oY16-9mtxIPslhPytmTa73JxQAjtyJuLRlljViw9FATWfatwqK0vZ9XD0XBBi2A1&t=635147041120000000");background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:right center;padding-right:14px; }
    #MenuPortail a.static.selected { background-color:SlateGray;border-color:SlateGray;border-width:1px;border-style:solid;text-decoration:none; }
    /* ]]> */
</style>
```

Comment: Would be helpful to include the markup for the nav menu as well. Also, you need to clarify what you're trying to achieve at the narrower device-widths.

Comment: Edited! What i'm trying to achieve is to change menu position from Horizontal to vertical when the windows gets minimized or at least reduce its width so it can be all mixed when the windows gets minmized!

Comment: rather than the asp markup, it would be better to include the rendered markup - you can probably just copy it from the view | source

Comment: And are you certain you've included all the relevant styles? By default your list should stack rather than lay out side by side, but there are no styles listed here that would make your menu behave like it currently is.

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by the rendered markup, kinakuta ? thank you

Comment: What you posted is the markup from your asp page. It's not what gets sent to the browser when the page is requested (the rendered markup.) If you view source on the actual web page, you'll see the rendered markup.

Comment: Edited! @kinakuta I've added some menu code from the view source feature of IE